# acts_as_commentable_with_threading + user accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

In my Rails app, I've integrated acts_as_commentable_with_threading in my Step model.  A user has many projects that each contain many steps, and users can comment on individual steps.  I've implemented this by adding acts_as_commentable to my step.rb model.

I recently came across an issue when a user deletes his account.  Is there something built in to acts_as_commentable to allow for associations between Users and the comments they've made (such as adding something like has_many :comment_threads in the user.rb file).  Since I don't have any associations, I started to run into some problems in my app where it was trying to reference a comment whose user no longer existed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way.  The fact that they're threaded throws a bit of a decision in destroying dependent records.  Personally I think if you have a threaded conversation and somewhere in that thread a comment is removed (because it's user object is previously removed) then all sub-threads of that comment should be removed.  That said, I do an after_destroy on user  to destroy all user comments and all sub threads of that user's comments:

```
after_destroy 'delete_comment_threads'


def delete_comment_threads
  comments = Comment.where(user_id: self.id)
  comments.each do |comment|
    Comment.destroy comment.children.map { |c| c.id }
  end
  Comment.destroy comments.map { |c| c.id }
end
```